# Image Transform of Transparent Images results with Black Background

Tags: image-transforms

As the title suggests, I am receiving a black background on my transparent PNGs. I'd prefer them to be white. I have enabled imagemagick in the config file but still no dice. I noticed GD library applies a similar black background so I'm thinking it's the process of conversion in Craft. Any suggestions?

See here:

CRAFT
http://staging.munacosealing.com/products/cut-gaskets-custom-gasekts-oem-gaskets-prototype-gaskets-asme-gaskets

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remedy this with a plugin (requires ImageMagick)
https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft#bgcolor-string